# Convert string formatted date to epoch

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert string formatted date to epoch format. Like the give date is in this format `2018, June 12th` how to convert it to epoch in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python datetime for all your date time related conversions.

```
fstring = "%Y, %B %d"
end = {"th" : fstring + "th", "rd": fstring + "rd"}
days = ["2018, June 12th", "2018, June 3rd"]
for day in days:
    fstr = end["rd"] if day.endswith("rd") else end["th"]
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(day, fstr).timestamp())

1528741800.0
1527964200.0
```

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: But I want some generalized for what if instead of 12th there is 3rd?